# Выбор ячейки согласно двух значений?

Tags: phpexcel

Как через PHPExcel выбрать ячейку из таблицы согласно двух значений.

Значение 1 столбца (ширина) и значение 1 строки (высота)
Нужно найти ячейку в массиве на месте их пересечения?

getCellByColumnAndRow

Ширину и длину - вводит пользователь.

Answer (score 0):

getCellByColumnAndRow(1,1) - Получить ячейку по определенной координате, используя числовые координаты ячейки

getCell(A,1) - Получить ячейку по определенной координате

Answer (score 0):

Это понимаю, не могу правильно прописать на php.
Где то допускаю ошибку, переменные вписать для поиска.
Любой пример как это сделано, пожалуйста.

Есть **два поля ввода** и **таблица excel**.
Первая колонка данные и первая строка с данными, внутри только цифры.

Допустим: вводит первое значение 2000 ищет по первой колонки, вводит второе значение 2000, ищет впервой строке.
И выводит данные ячейки на месте их пересечения.